# equivalente a BDEXTRAER para extraer un dato por FILA y no por columna

Tags: excel

alguien me puede ayudar con este problema con mi libro de excel?

tengo una tabla de 2 columnas(código y descripcion) y 20 filas,y otra pestaña con una base de datos, cuando introduzca un código me tiene que aparece un resultado en la celda de al lado, y asi en cada una de las filas.

Consigo algo parecido con BDEXTRAER pero solo funciona con un dato y columna. De que manera puedo extraer datos por linea?

Gracias

Comment: Posiblemente con BUSCARV y, además, dependiendo de tu versión de Excel, puede que notación matricial haga que la fórmula se extienda a más filas. Quizás también con ÍNDICE, pero habría que ver cómo tienes estructurados los datos y un ejemplo de lo que quieres conseguir.